# Grails use Command Object and object in the same gsp

Tags: grails, gsp, grails-controller, command-objects

I have a controller, edit method paint the user info in the form file. But
when I try to update with errors the command object return userCommand object so I lost all info from user object.

Is there any way to use both in the same form? or what I'm missing here.

UserController class

```
class UserController {
    def edit(User user) {
        respond user
    }
    def update(UserCommand userCommand) {
        log.debug "Update a User"

        if (userCommand.hasErrors()) {
            respond userCommand.errors, view: 'edit'
            return
        }
     }
}
```

_form.gsp file

```
<g:form action="update">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="firstName">User First Name</label>
        <input class="form-control" name="firstName" value="${user?.firstName}">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="lastName">User Last Name</label>
        <input class="form-control" name="lastName" value="${user?.lastName}">
    </div>
</g:form>
```

[image: when call edit method, I get the user info]

[image: Update with errors, I got lost the user info]

Comment: Did you try to respond just userCommand instead of userCommand.errors?

Comment: Yes I did. same result

Comment: ahhh :) instead of user?.firstName try to use userCommand?.firstName

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Thank you @tuomas-valtonen. You drive me to find the solution.

```
def edit(User user) {
        UserCommand userCommand = new UserCommand()
        bindData(userCommand, user)
        respond userCommand
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

You should use `UserCommand` on both actions parameter and create your User object inside the action from UserCommand by `data binding`. This is to separate your View Model from the actual Model.

Like other users stated, return the whole `UserCommand` instead of `UserCommand.errors`. You can access `UserCommand.errors` in the view also.

Remember, that after your UserCommand is valid, you still need to create User and validate it and return any errors it has. Both can be run through `<g:renderErrors bean="${user}">` for example.